# The LINQ expression could be translated

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to apply some advanced filtering in EF core but getting error;
Here is my code:

```cs
private IQueryable<AppDataUsage> PrepareDataUsageFilter(IQueryable<AppDataUsage> dataUsageReports, DataUsageFilter dataUsageFilter, List<AppDataUsageSettings> reportSettings, AppDataUsageSettings defaultSetting, int minData, int MaxData)
{
    if (dataUsageFilter == DataUsageFilter.Custom)
    {
        return dataUsageReports.Where(a => a.TotalMobileDataUsage >= minData && a.TotalMobileDataUsage <= MaxData);
    }
    else if (dataUsageFilter == DataUsageFilter.Exceeded)
    {
        return dataUsageReports.Where(a => a.TotalMobileDataUsage > GetDataLimit(a, reportSettings, defaultSetting));
    }
    else if (dataUsageFilter == DataUsageFilter.Approaching)
    {
        return dataUsageReports.Where(a => a.TotalMobileDataUsage >= GetDataLimit(a, reportSettings, defaultSetting) &&
            a.TotalMobileDataUsage < GetDataWarning(a, reportSettings, defaultSetting));
    }

    return dataUsageReports;
}

private static byte GetDataLimit(AppDataUsage dataUsage, List<AppDataUsageSettings> reportSettings, AppDataUsageSettings defaultSetting)
{
    var policyId = dataUsage.PolicyId;
    var groupId = dataUsage.GroupId;

    var dataLimit = reportSettings
        .Where(r => r.SettingMappings.Any(x => x.ObjectId == policyId || x.ObjectId == groupId))
        .Select(r => r.DataLimit)
        .DefaultIfEmpty(defaultSetting.DataLimit)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    return dataLimit;
}

private static int GetDataWarning(AppDataUsage dataUsage, List<AppDataUsageSettings> reportSettings, AppDataUsageSettings defaultSetting)
{
    var policyId = dataUsage.PolicyId;
    var groupId = dataUsage.GroupId;

    var dataWarning = reportSettings
        .Where(r => r.SettingMappings.Any(x => x.ObjectId == policyId || x.ObjectId == groupId))
        .Select(r => r.DataWarning)
        .DefaultIfEmpty(defaultSetting.DataWarning)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    return dataWarning;
}

//Calling
 dataUsageReports = PrepareDataUsageFilter(dataUsageReports, dto.DataUsageFilterType, reportSettings, defaultSetting, dto.MinData, dto.MaxData);

 var totalCount = dataUsageReports.Count();

 var chartData = await dataUsageReports.GroupBy(a => a.ReportedOn).Select(r => new GetAppDataUsageChartDto { 
     Date = r.Key,
     MobileDataUsage = r.Sum(a => a.TotalMobileDataUsage),
     WifiDataUsage = r.Sum(a => a.TotalWifiUsage)
 }).ToListAsync();

 var gridData = await dataUsageReports.OrderByDescending(a => a.TotalMobileDataUsage).Skip(dto.SkipCount).Take(dto.MaxResultCount).Select(d => new AppDataUsageWithTotalCountDto
 {
     DeviceUniqueIdentifier = d.DeviceUniqueIdentifier,
     MobileDataUsage = d.TotalMobileDataUsage,
     WifiDataUsage = d.TotalWifiUsage,
     TotalCount = totalCount,
     DataLimit = GetDataLimit(d, reportSettings, defaultSetting),
     DataWarning = GetDataWarning(d, reportSettings, defaultSetting)
 }).ToListAsync();
```

The error says "The LINQ expression could be translated". I assume that's because of the way I am trying to Get "DataLimit" and "DataWarning" But not sure how can I fix this. The reason of creating separate functions is because I need the same thing at multiple places within a single method

Comment: Did you search for that error? There are several dozen duplicate questions. LINQ over EF gets translated to SQL that runs on the server. You can't call local functions from the server, or use functions that can't be translated to SQL

Comment: I did and indeed found many links but I am not very sure about my specific use case

Comment: It's the same use case. There's no way to convert the client-side `GetDataLimit` and `GetDataWarning` function calls to SQL. If `AppDataUsageSettings` data is loaded from the database you can create  a SQL query that combines your report query and that data on the server.

Comment: Also pretty sure the error message is "linq expression could NOT be translated" . You should update your post and title.

Comment: You cannot use custom methods inside EF Core LINQ query. `GetDataLimit` is definetely not translatable. Try to write this code inside `Where` body.

Comment: I tried moving it to a where clause but still getting same error

Comment: `GetDataWarning` also.

Comment: Yes, moved both with the same logic in where clause

Comment: return dataUsageReports.Where(a => a.TotalMobileDataUsage > reportSettings
  .Where(r => r.SettingMappings.Any(x => x.ObjectId == a.PolicyId || x.ObjectId == a.GroupId))
  .Select(r => r.DataLimit)
  .DefaultIfEmpty(defaultSetting.DataLimit)
  .FirstOrDefault());

Comment: There is another problem. EF Core supports only `Contains`  with local collections. From where you gent `reportSettings`?

Comment: var reportSettings = await context.AppDataUsageSettings.Where(a => (a.TenantId == dto.TenantId || a.Title == AppConsts.DefaultReportSettingProfile) && !a.IsDeleted).ToListAsync();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has several problems:

1. Usage of custom functions in LINQ query: `GetDataLimit` and `GetDataWarning`
2. Using local collections in query. EF Core supports only `Contains` operator with local collections

At first, do not materialize `reportSettings`, leave it as `IQueryable`

```cs
var reportSettings = context.AppDataUsageSettings
    .Where(a => (a.TenantId == dto.TenantId || a.Title == AppConsts.DefaultReportSettingProfile) && !a.IsDeleted);
```

Then correct your query, using `LEFT JOIN` to limited recordset:

```cs
private IQueryable<AppDataUsage> PrepareDataUsageFilter(IQueryable<AppDataUsage> dataUsageReports, DataUsageFilter dataUsageFilter, IQueryable<AppDataUsageSettings> reportSettings, AppDataUsageSettings defaultSetting, int minData, int MaxData)
{
    if (dataUsageFilter == DataUsageFilter.Custom)
    {
        dataUsageReports = dataUsageReports.Where(a => a.TotalMobileDataUsage >= minData && a.TotalMobileDataUsage <= MaxData);
    }
    else if (dataUsageFilter == DataUsageFilter.Exceeded)
    {
        dataUsageReports = 
            from ur in dataUsageReports
            from rs in reportSettings
                .Where(rs => rs.SettingMappings.Any(x => x.ObjectId == policyId || x.ObjectId == groupId))
                .Take(1)
                .DefaultIfEmpty()
            where ur.TotalMobileDataUsage > ((int?)ur.DataLimit ?? defaultSetting.DataLimit) 
            select ur;

        dataUsageReports = dataUsageReports.Where(a => a.TotalMobileDataUsage > GetDataLimit(a, reportSettings, defaultSetting));
    }
    else if (dataUsageFilter == DataUsageFilter.Approaching)
    {
        dataUsageReports = 
            from ur in dataUsageReports
            from rs in reportSettings
                .Where(rs => rs.SettingMappings.Any(x => x.ObjectId == policyId || x.ObjectId == groupId))
                .Take(1)
                .DefaultIfEmpty()
            where ur.TotalMobileDataUsage >= ((int?)ur.DataLimit ?? defaultSetting.DataLimit)  && a.TotalMobileDataUsage < ((int?)ur.DataWarning ?? defaultSetting.DataWarning)
            select ur;
    }

    return dataUsageReports;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. One more question, in the selection, I want to get the values. Can i use the method in Selection?
var gridData = await dataUsageReports.Skip(dto.SkipCount).Take(dto.MaxResultCount).Select(d => new AppDataUsageWithTotalCountDto
{
    DeviceUniqueIdentifier = d.DeviceUniqueIdentifier,
    MobileDataUsage = d.TotalMobileDataUsage,
    WifiDataUsage = d.TotalWifiUsage,
    TotalCount = totalCount,
    DataLimit = GetDataLimit(d, reportSettings, defaultSetting),
    DataWarning = GetDataWarning(d, reportSettings, defaultSetting)
}).ToListAsync();

Comment: I've updated my question. Please see the //Calling part

Comment: You can, but is bad idea for performance. All information can be retrieved from queries which i have made.